# php sql statement formation

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to take the entire post array and put each value into a select statement that will update the previous value. I am having trouble doing this in php with string escaping.

This is the SQL statement I am trying to pass:

```
UPDATE test1l.testtable SET age=106, weight=345, WHERE id=11
```

So the submission page first puts the $_POST array into a variable. Then I try to set the statement up so that each post variable is in the right place.

```
$dataArray = $_POST;
$Sql =" UPDATE test1l.testtable SET age=$dataArray['age'],weight=$dataArray['weight'] WHERE id=$dataArray['id']"
```

The single and double quotes are messing my statement up. Also, I have a custom function that is character escaping these strings so as to help stop injection.

Comment: Remove the commas before WHERE: `UPDATE test1l.testtable SET age=106, weight=345 WHERE id=11`

Comment: I am having problems putting this into a php string. Like where to put what quotes. That was just a copy pasta error

Comment: "I have a custom function that is character escaping these strings so as to help stop injection." Why use a custom function? There already builtin functions for doing this.

Comment: $query = "UPDATE test1l.testtable SET age=$dataArray['age'],weight=$dataArray['weight'] WHERE id=$dataArray['id']"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use concatenation :

```
'update ... SET age = ' . $dataArray['age'] . ', weight = ...'
```

And make sure to validate and properly escape your post attributes to avoid SQL injection. Or even better: use prepared statements to be sure. See http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 1):

Store the verified user input ([`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for unknown input) in a variable, then use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) as shown below. This line of code will never break, unless some of the variables are not defined, or if the database information is incorrect.

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE test1l.testtable SET age='%s', weight='%s' WHERE id='%s'", $age, $weight, $id);
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this would be safer:

```
$dataArray = $_POST; 
$Sql =" UPDATE test1l.testtable SET age=?, weight=? WHERE id=?";
$Statement = $mysqli->prepare($Sql);
$Statement->bind_param('iii', $dataArray['age'], 
                              $dataArray['weight'], 
                              $dataArray['id']);
$Statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going with a format like this:

```
$Sql =" UPDATE test1l.testtable SET age=$dataArray['age'],weight=$dataArray['weight'] WHERE id=$dataArray['id']"
```

It should be done like this:

```
$Sql ="UPDATE test1l.testtable SET age={$dataArray['age']},weight={$dataArray['weight']} WHERE id={$dataArray['id']}";
```

You have to surround complex variables like array and objects with {} when working inside double quotes.

```
$string = "print {$object->param} and {$array['key']}";
```

Also don't forget your query is dealing with all integer fields - once you get to string fields in the db like varchar, char, text - you're query must surround these in single quotes like this:

```
$Sql ="UPDATE test1l.textfield SET textfield='{$dataArray['age']}' WHERE id={$dataArray['id']}";
```

Also as mentioned any variable based on user input intended for part of an SQL statment should be using either parametrized statements or the function mysql_real_escape_string.

As a note this is where you must change to a string building format more like:

```
$sql= 'UPDATE test1l.testtable SET age='.mysql_real_escape_string($dataArray['age']).', weight='.mysql_real_escape_string($dataArray['weight']).' WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string($dataArray['id']);
```

And ideally you would extract this into a reusable function that would sanitize all fields intended for the database with mysql_real_escape_string, so you don't have to keep making such ugly/unreadable sql strings.

Answer (score 0):

i do it like this

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE test1l.testtable SET age='".$dataArray['age']."',
            weight='".$dataArray['weight']."' WHERE id='".$dataArray['id']."' ")
```

just incase you were unaware, you can remove the ticks from inside the brackets:  `$dataArray[age]`